# Is there a way to better deal with my 8 neighboring values check on a grid?

Tags: java

As of right now i have created a working set of code that takes a grid value defined by **GRID** below. When i am doing this check I am uncertain of if the the value will coincide with multiple out of bounds issues. I am not showing all the code but to elaborate this code is wrapped in a for loop for the entire size of the Grid from which the value E is the base point. This for loop uses x and y so assume that e = the value found at that point in the grid. Besides all that I was wondering if it was possible to reduce the redundancies of this code and make it much simpler without loosing the functionality.

```
 //assume e has been checked to be in bounds already but the outside squares have not 
//(and that they need to have there data changed if out of bounds to = e and if not then they need to be changed to the value at that point in the grid)
    double a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,f=0,g=0,h=0,i=0;
    boolean ay = false,by= false,cy= false,dy= false,fy= false,gy= false,hy= false,iy= false;
                            if (x==0) 
                            {a=e;d=e;g=e;
                             ay = true;dy = true;gy = true;}
                            if (y==0) 
                            {a=e;b=e;c=e;
                            ay = true;by = true;cy = true;}
                            if (x== grid.length-1)
                            {c= e;f=e;i=e;
                            cy = true;fy = true;iy = true;}                 
                            if (y== grid.length-1)
                            {g=e;h=e;i=e;
                            gy = true;hy = true;iy = true;}

                            if (ay== false)
                                a =grid(y-1, x-1);
                            if (by== false)
                                b= grid(y-1,x);
                            if (cy== false)
                                c =grid(y-1,x+1);
                            if (dy== false)
                                d =grid(y,x-1);
                            if (fy== false)
                                f =grid(y,x+1);
                            if (gy== false)
                                g =grid(y+1,x-1);
                            if (hy== false)
                                h= grid(y+1,x);
                            if (iy== false)
                                i =grid(y+1,x+1);
```

***Edit:***
This code is meant to pull data from a grid and use it for a calculation of slope. If there is no data(or it is out of bounds) at a given point then the data is given the value of the center. The goal of this portion of code is to ensure there is no null point error when checking the data of the array.

Comment: There are some questions that make me cringe and just close it - sorry, perhaps someone braver than I will have the strength to help.

Comment: If you guys need clarification i will be more then glad to update my post with the details or down here.

Comment: Perhaps just describe exactly what the code is **supposed** to do.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon how so? i understand that the question may seem off due to how i have written it. i indeed Understand that this is a very horrible form of coding and that it should be burned with fire hence why when going through my initial thought was to check the if the values were in the correct area of the array then to check if they are inside. i would have loved to used the null check to make this look better but unfortunately the extent of double values does not except null values hence the boolean values.

Comment: Updated with more info .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Math methods to allow you to do some simplification and clarification:

```
int minI = Math.max(x - 1, 0);
int maxI = Math.min(grid.length - 1, x + 1)
int minJ = Math.max(y - 1, 0);
int maxJ = Math.min(grid.length - 1, y + 1)

for (int i = minI; i <= maxI; i++) {
    for (int j = minJ; j <= maxJ; j++) {
        if (i != x && j != y) {
            // do your test in here
        }
    }
}
```

or something like this would work

Comment: in reading through this is it true that what this code will do is determine a range of numbers to pull as long as they are inbounds? I have looked at this as a posible solution but find that all the values outside of the data are excluded in this solution.

Comment: I assume that this is better suited for arrays of data correct? if so then I would also like to assume that the if statement nested inside of the for statements could have a else statement to include the values outside of the range?